# Regex PCRE pattern to select all routes starting with /first-url-segment/ AND do not include "iframe" in the latter part of the URL

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, web-application-firewall

I am trying to filter out paths that start with certain string but do not have the "iframe" substring in it.
Here is what seems to be working for me https://regex101.com/r/rIMFDP/1

```
^\/csr_and_sustainability_information\/(?!.*iframe)
```

but on amazon this regex doesnt work https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-regex-pattern-set-creating.html

It states

> AWS WAF supports the pattern syntax used by the PCRE library libpcre

I wonder if its possible to reproduce what I want within that standard

So I want select all routes starting with /csr_and_sustainability_information/ AND do not include **"iframe"** in the latter part of the URL

Comment: I'd guess you're running into the latter notation `AWS WAF doesn't support all contructs of the library`. Likely lookaheads aren't supported. Can you have two constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a POSIX compliant regex like

```js
^/csr_and_sustainability_information/([^i]|i(i|f(i|r(i|a(i|mi))))*([^fi]|f([^ir]|r([^ai]|a([^im]|m[^ei])))))*(i(i|f(i|r(i|a(i|mi))))*(f(r?|ram?))?)?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGdhQh/1)

The `([^i]|i(i|f(i|r(i|a(i|mi))))*([^fi]|f([^ir]|r([^ai]|a([^im]|m[^ei])))))*(i(i|f(i|r(i|a(i|mi))))*(f(r?|ram?))?)?$` part makes sure there is no `iframe` string after `/csr_and_sustainability_information/`.

Comment: Why no escape before the forward slash ? like this \/ . Is escape necessary?

Comment: @Hairi No, it is only required when the forward slash is used as a regex delimiter. By itself, `/` is not any special regex metacharacter, so no need to escape it. You have no regex delimiters in the regex in the question.